# How to automatically update values referenced from one sheet to another in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

Here is my problem. I have 2 to 3 worksheets, and I need to make a master worksheet. The 2-3 worksheets contain the sales made in the day and the customer name. The problem is that new customers come everyday. I need Excel to automatically update the values in the master worksheet when a change is made in the 2 to 3 sheets. Can someone please help?

Comment: No guys I can reference . I cannot update my work . Suppose sheet1 has 5 people and I have referenced it in my master sheet . now two more people buy stuff and become seven . how do I automatically update it to the master file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference a worksheet within the same file using `<SHEETNAME>!` e.g. `=Sales!B1` where 'Sales' is the worksheet name as defined at the bottom of your Excel window

Answer (score 0):

When writing the formulas, and still in the text box to type them out, use your mouse to switch to the other workbook/spreadsheet and click on the external cell you'd like to reference in the calculation. Excellent will automatically insert the reference into the formula.  This only works if you are editing the destination cell.

E.g. Select cell. Press "=". Navigate to other sheet. Click reference cell(s).